# Kafka streams KTable creation from a given topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I'm doing a project and I'm stuck on the KTable.

I want to take records from a topic and put them in a KTable(store), so that I have 1 record for 1 key.

```
    static KafkaStreams streams;

    final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();
    final Serde<byte[]> byteSerde = Serdes.ByteArray();
    static String topicName;
    static String storeName;
    final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    KStream<Long, byte[]> streamed = builder.stream(topicName, Consumed.with(longSerde, byteSerde));
    KTable<Long, byte[]> records = streamed.groupByKey().reduce(
            new Reducer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long apply(Long aggValue, Long newValue) {
                    return newValue;
                }
            }, 
            storeName);
```

This is the closest I got to the answer I think.

Comment: Why don't you use `builder.table()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, but you need to use the correct serdes.

In *.reduce()* function, value type should be `byte[]`.

```
 KStream<Long, byte[]> streamed = builder.stream(topicName, Consumed.with(longSerde, byteSerde));
 KTable<Long, byte[]> records = streamed.groupByKey().reduce(
            new Reducer<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public byte[] apply(byte[] aggValue, byte[] newValue) {
                    return newValue;
                }
            }, 
            Materialized.as(storename).with(longSerde,byteSerde));
```

Comment: but it's not working this way, it gives the following exception `The method reduce(Reducer<byte[]>, Materialized<Long,byte[],KeyValueStore<Bytes,byte[]>>) in the type KGroupedStream<Long,byte[]> is not applicable for the arguments (new Reducer<byte[]>(){}, String)`

Comment: I also changed `Reducer<Long>` to `Reducer<byte[]>`

Comment: I removed `storeName` at the end, and now it is not giving the exception, I also want to ask you, where do I save this KTable, and how to get values from it?

Comment: Yeah, .reduce() doesn't have a implementation to add storename as string. Instead you need to give the Materialized.  There you can define the serde and store name. Updated the answer

Comment: Also, if you want to use the state store for interactive queries, then you should pass a store name otherwise it uses the internal name.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I don't want to use it as interactive queries, I wanted to use the store so I can store the data and when some time is passed, I want to retrieve the data from the store by the key and do some logic to it, then produce it to another topic, for another `microservice`

Comment: Why don't you use `builder.table()` ?